# Opening a local executable jar via Javascript or HTML5

Tags: java, html, applet, load

I am trying to execute a local executable jar from an html page, so I originally tried using javascript window.open("/Users/guest/desktop/fileName").  This almost works.  It opens up the folder where the jar is located and selects the jar, but it does not execute the jar.  Then I saw threads on here about how opening the file is not possible because of security problems.

I came across this page, which I feel like should have my answer:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

But all that page talks about is how to read and write to files, not how to open them.  Is opening local files still not possible? If it is, how can I go about it?

Here is my HTML code in case it may help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win()
{window.open("/Desktop/folder/jarFile.jar")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Open jar" onclick="open_win()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *open*? Do you want to list the files inside the JAR or do you want to execute it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to execute it.

Comment: So what you want is this: You open a Website and then this website executes a program on your pc....sounds like a big security problem. For example you could make a webpage "www.delete.com" which deletes your whole hdd if you open it?

Comment: Right, but this "website" would just be for my own use and convenience.  It would only be used locally.

Comment: hm okay so you just want to run a jar-file on your local pc...why not just click on the jar to execute it, or use a small script, or put it in a exe (if you are on windows)?

Comment: Thank you. I was just trying to simplify it by reducing the number of clicks that were necessary.  Most likely I will end up clicking on the jar.

Comment: May I ask WHY you want to do this?

Comment: That's a fair question.  Eventually this is going to go on a computer besides my own, and only that one computer.  It will provide a cleaner, more convenient way for the users of that computer to access the files they need to access.  I have a java program that complements the web pages, and this program is currently in an executable jar file.  I would like for users to be able to execute the JAR by clicking on a javascript button or an html link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do that. If you need to execute a jar, you should look into JavaWebstart (and serve that jar from the server).

Comment: Do I still need to deal with servers if I only want to use the jar on one computer that I have access to?

Comment: So you don't even have a web server? Because that's all you need for Java WebStart!

Comment: *"Do I still need to deal with servers"*  Yes, with JWS the Jar needs to be first delivered from the server.  You are using the wrong interface (browser) to launch the Jar.  Instead make it 'double click to start' and drag it or a shortcut to the desktop.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice.  @AndrewThompson It works from my desktop as is, I'm trying to get it to run by clicking on a button in an HTML page.  I have not tried a JWS yet.